# Maximum possible dimension of space of 10x10 real symmetric commutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

Let $V$ be a nonempty subset of all $10 \times 10$ real symmetric commutative matrices. What is the maximum possible dimension of $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

What I know so far: I believe that for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the dimension of all the $n \times n$ real symmetric matrices would be $\frac{n^2 + n}{2}$ (e.g. for symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices we'd have $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \right\}$ as a basis, and $(2^2 + 2)/2 = 3$, so the rule checks out in this caes.) So I'm pretty sure that $\dim V \leq (10^2 + 10)/2 = 55$. Now I'm trying to figure out: does the added property that the matrices in $V$ commute give a better bound? I'm a bit stuck and could use some insight...Does simultaneous diagonalizability come into play somehow?

Comment: what exactly are "commutative" matrices? A subset s.t. for all $A,B$ in this subset we have $AB=BA$?

Comment: What do you know about symmetric matrices that commute? There is a very particular theorem about those. If you know, you know, and this question becomes rather easy. If you don't know, then this is a pretty tricky problem.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure about the result that you're referring to, but the result that the asker seems to be referencing regarding simultaneously diagonalizable matrices that also makes quick work of this problem

Comment: @LegNaiB: Yes, that's what I meant by commutative.

Comment: @Arthur: I don't think I'm aware of the particular theorem you are referring to. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @Leonidas You can use the fact that the matrices must be simultaneously diagonalizable to show that the dimension is at most $10$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Ok, so there exists an invertible matrix $P \in V$ such that $P^{-1} A P$ is a diagonal matrix for all $A \in V$. Which means every matrix $A \in V$ can be written as $A = PDP^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $D \in V$. So my intuition is that the matrix $P$ has to do with the basis matrices, and the diagonal elements of $D$ correspond to the coefficients in the linear combo of matrices. I'm not quite sure how to proceed though...